# How can i create this function?

Tags: c

I've wrote a program that read 5 numbers, put them into an array, print them and prints the same numbers but backwards. Now i wanna add a function that counts how many time a number that the user puts into the array is repeated, how can i do this?. I can't use pointers (Because my teacher hasn't explained them yet so i wanna try to make this program without them).

```
void read_numbers(int array[]);

void print_number(int array[]);

void reverse_numbers(int array[]);

int main (){
int array[5];
read_numbers(array);
print_number(array);
reverse_numbers(array);
}

void read_numbers(int array[]){
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    printf("Insert numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    i++;
}
}

void print_numbers(int array[]){
int i = 0;
printf("\n");
while (i < 5) {
    printf("%d\n", vettore[i]);
    i++;
}
}

void reverse_numbers(int vettore[]){
int j = 5;
int i = j-1;
printf("\n");
while (i>=0) {
    printf("%d\n", vettore[i--]);
}
}
```

The output that i want for this new function is similar to this:

The k number has been repeated n times in the array.

P.S: Recently i've edited the question because i've seen some comments that says that the question isn't clear or that i should give an example about the output that i want

Comment: You are already using pointers in functions as for example in the function print_numbers that has a parameter of a pointer type.:) That is this declaration void print_number(int array[]); is adjusted to the declaration void print_number(int *array);

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem with the function.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to clarify. See [mcve]. I suggest posting an example of user input to your program, and what you expect it to output.

Comment: C functions by tradition take an array *and* a size parameter. Don't stuff literal `5` in your code everywhere. Make that an argument.

Comment: Could you please give a example what you mean by duplicates and how it should be counted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// for each number in array
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    int repeated = 0;
    
    // check is number repeated
    for(int j=0; j < 5; j++){
        if(i != j && array[i] == array[j])
            repeated++;
    }

    printf("%d has been repeated %d times\n", array[i], repeated);
}
```

Comment: Now try your code with the array { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

Comment: The problem was in the last line, Have to use `array[i]` instead `i` in `printf` arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array again

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
  {
    int repeat_count = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++)
    {
        if(array[i] == array[j]) repeat_count++;
    }   
  }
```

Repeat count is no. of times it is occuring in the array so it won't ever be less than 1.
If you want to get repeated times just subtract 1 from it when you are printing.

Comment: We can stores answer to avoid checking again for same but that will just complicate things.

Comment: So your solution does not make a sense.

Comment: It will tell element at position 0 is appearing in array 5 times. same with position 2 and so on. It is still correct but can be improved. but that will make it difficult for him to understand.

Comment: And what about the element in the position 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this.
My code count the number of duplicates so if you run it it returns 4 because 3 has 3 duplicates and 2 has 1 duplicate. So 3+1 = 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[8] = {3,3,3,2,1,2,5,3};
    int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<8;i++){
            for (int j = i+1;j<8;j++){
                if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
    printf("%d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not make a sense.

Comment: My code count the number of duplicates so if you run it it returns 4 because 3 has 3 duplicates and 2 has 1 duplicate. So 3+1 = 4. And if you try to run it with {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} it returns 7 like it should do.

Comment: But your code says nothing about how many times 1 or 5 is repeated in your original  array.

Comment: yes because it return the total number of duplicates, it works well with every set of values trust me, I've tried it before posting.

Comment: But in the question there is written write "a function that counts how many time a number that the user puts into the array is repeated" In your original array 5 is put in it.